# Android 6 / Samsung network issue

Tags: android, udp, android-wifi, samsung-mobile

I've developed an Android app for remote controlling some special hardware devices. The communication is done via udp and wifi. The app already runs on ~60k devices without any problems but since the rollout of Android 6 I'm getting more and more reports from users who get some strange errors:

Usually the app searches for the hardware with a broadcast package. The app then requests all data from the hardware to stay in sync (~4000 packages in both directions). This sync process is heavily tested with all wifi conditions possible and does work as intended (also on Android 6).

User with a Samsung device and Android 6 are now having the issue, that the sync is unable to complete (no reply from the hardware within 20 seconds). The odd thing is that the broadcast search does work just fine, as well as the beginning of the sync. Usually the timeout happens when 5-15% of the sync was completed.

As I have no idea what could cause this issue I wanted to ask if there is any known problems with Samsung / Android 6 and udp communication via wifi?
Also were there any other changes on the network stack in Android 6 that could cause this issue? On my test devices (HTC mostly) everything runs fine so I'm currently out of ideas.

Edit:
I narrowed the issue down to the following devices:

- Samsung Galaxy 6
- Samsung Galaxy 6 Edge
- Samsung Galaxy Note 5

Edit 2:
I got a Samsung Galaxy 6 device for testing purposes and of course it does work for me. I also tried all sorts of network setup, power saving, anti virus and general settings combination but it's just working all the time.

Edit 3:
After getting some Galaxy S5 and S6 test devices I was not able to reproduce the problem. Comparing the ROM version I found out that these devices all have a newer rom than the devices which got the issues.
Turns out that Samsung simply broke something in their wifi stack which causes the wifi to stop working properly after some udp packages. So only fix for this issue is to wait and hope they fix it in all countries soon.

Comment: have you found answer or just 'we waiting to samsung bug fix'?)

Comment: I've got no new answer. Samsung fixed the issue in most countries but some carried do not distribute the update.